# Why eels don't attack in the pool in "A cure for wellness"?

Tags: plot-explanation, a-cure-for-wellness

In the [**A Cure for Wellness**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4731136/)... there is a scene where Hanna goes into the swimming pool.

Eels come out.

Similarly there are eels that eat humans. That is how they dispose dead bodies.

Now question... why don't the eels attack Hanna after she starts bleeding?

First they act like they are about to attack her then they all just swim in circle fashion around her.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

ref : [**A Cure For Wellness Explanation**](https://www.thisisbarry.com/single-post/2017/09/20/A-Cure-For-Wellness-2016-Movie-Plot-Ending-Explained)

Something made Hannah survive as a fetus when she was thrown into the water. Perhaps it was because the way Hannah was conceived. The Baron gives his sister the eel elixir. Hanna was conceived as a result...

> However, the Baron’s sister is unable to conceive. She’s infertile.
>   The Baron begins looking for a cure and experiments on the town’s
>   people. Slowly the town starts finding dried up corpses of missing
>   people.

She was thrown into the aquifer that these eels live in. The elixir is made from a combination of the eels and aquifer's water. The same combination helps Hannah survive as a fetus in the aquifer. She shares that bond with the eels.

> Meanwhile, Hannah steps into another pool where eels show up.
>   Initially, they get ready to attack her but then Hannah bleeds from
>   her periods. The eels mysteriously swim in circles around her. Perhaps
>   it has something to do with her as a fetus surviving in the eel filled
>   aquifer.

The eels are familiar with her blood as it is off their own. Hence the don't attack her and stop just outside the extent of her bleeding. The Baron on the other hand is naturally born and doesn't share anything with the eels. He only consumes the elixir to extend his life. He is not born because of the elixir.